# Compiling with make gives me the error: cc1plus: error: unrecognized argument to ‘-flto=’ option: ‘auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto’

Tags: make, cmake

I'm trying to compile [this code](https://github.com/lanl/vpic) whith the procedure that apears in the site. I make a new "build" folder and i use the command "cmake .." after i enter the folder, but when i use the "make" command it gives me the error.
I have Ubuntu version 22.04, gcc version 11.3.0, make version 4.3 and already installed mpi.
The whole error is this:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized argument to ‘-flto=’ option: ‘auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto’
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/vpic.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/vpic.dir/src/boundary/absorb_tally.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/vpic.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code. Also add the version of Ubuntu you're running to the question.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"whith the procedure that apears in the site"*? Which implementation of MPI are you using? Which `../arch/xxx` script did you select? I just tried it on a 22.04 VM with openmpi and `../arch/gcc/reference-Release` and everything seemed to build OK

Comment: The procedure is making a new folder in "vpic" called "build", after that i use "cmake .." in the folder. Until this point everything runs good, but when i use make the error apears. I've tried using "../arch/reference-Release" and the problem persists

Comment: I'm using the MPI that is included in gcc

Answer (score 0):

Have you suceed in solving this problem? I've encountered a similar question when compiling a self-made code on a new computer.

Comment: I've succeeded to solve this problem. A way to solve this is that you can remove the ```‘-flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto’```  flag in your cmakecache file or your cmakelist file.